# How to solve the ambiguous error of this template function

Tags: c++, templates, template-function

I have wrote a template function which is used to test if there is a key or value in the given container.

```
template<typename T>
bool has_key(const T &t, const typename T::key_type &key) {
    return t.find(key) != t.end();
}
template<typename T>
bool has_key(const T &t, const typename T::value_type &v) {
    for (auto i = t.begin(); i != t.end(); i++) {
        if (*i == v) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It works fine with `std::map` and `std::vector`. But when the container is `std::set`, an ambiguous error is found. Because the `std::set` defined both `key_type` and `value_type`, and they are the same type. So my question is how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Why are they both named `has_key`? The second seems like it should be called `has_value`.

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel in the second overload? It should just be `return std::find(t.begin(), t.end(), v) != t.end()`. In fact, both overloads should probably just return the iterator, and single, separate function could do the comparison against `end()`.

Comment: I'm pretty certain `key_value` should've been `key_type` in your code. Let me know if the edit was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Using std::set both method will have the same signatures. You need to disambiguate it by changing one of the methods name or adding a dummy parameter. E.g.

```
bool has_key_for_value(const T &t, const typename T::value_type &v);
```

Notice however that you can easily solve your problem directly using [std::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/)

Comment: Even without changing the name, it should still be possible to use SFINAE to make things work if `key_type` is the same as `value_type`.

Comment: Yes, I want that solution. I have tried to add a dummy parameter, but failed.